# Async loop with generator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have to run a series of async tasks sequentially with a delay between each task until a certain is met. I try to do this with es6 generator. Here is the code

```
function delay(callback, timeout) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => {
        try {
            resolve(callback());
        } catch(e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    }, timeout));
}

function run(generatorFunc) {
    function continuer(verb, arg) {
        var result;
        try {
            result = generator[verb](arg);
        } catch (err) {
            return Promise.reject(err);
        }
        if (result.done) {
            return Promise.resolve(result.value);
        } else {
            return Promise.resolve(result.value).then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
        }
    }
    var generator = generatorFunc();
    var onFulfilled = continuer.bind(continuer, "next");
    var onRejected = continuer.bind(continuer, "throw");
    return onFulfilled();
}

run(function* () {
    var json;
    while (true) {
        json = yield delay(() => fetch('http://api.com/get.json').then(res => res.json()), 1000)
        if (json.isCompleted) {
            return json;
        }
    }
}).then(json => console.log(json));
```

Now i want to "break" that promise chain if the user presses a button, how i can do that without introducing a global variable? Thanks

Comment: So you want to chance the value of while(true) to while(false) without using a global var? A conceptual "kill function"? Why can't you use a global var?

Comment: you can't impact the inner workings of s function from the outside without the function providing some kind of hook.

Comment: Tip: if you call `generatorInstance.throw()` it will throw from this part of your code. If you call `generatorInstance.next(arg)` `arg` will replace expression that is yielded.

Comment: You can `Promise.race` your `fetch()`es against a `getUserButtonClick()` promise, and then `break` the loop when a click event is passed in instead of a json. Or do you mean you want to break the `run` function, regardless of how the generator function looks like?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  const run = task => {
    const taskState = task();
    let reject = null;
    const process = new Promise((rs, rj) => {
      (function next (dat) {
        const {value, done} = taskState.next(dat);
        (done) ? rs(value) : value.then(next).catch(reason => rj(reason));
      }());
      reject = rj;
    });
    //
    // Expose *hook* like what @Felix Kling suggested
    //  
    process.kill = sig => {
      taskState.return(); // close generator
      reject(sig); // reject promise
    };
    return process;
  }

  // To test interrupt, we create a task involving a async task which is 'idle' forever
  function* task () {
    // imagine big memory has been already allocated here
    // and one async task ... does not response ...
    yield new Promise(() => {}); /*pending forever*/
  }

  // setup process, we'll see 'KILL' or 'TIMEOUT' on console.error channel
  let process = run(task);
  process.catch(e => console.error('stderr', e)).then(/*never*/);

  // interrupt cases
  document.body.addEventListener('click', e => process.kill('KILL'));
  setTimeout(() => process.kill('TIMEOUT'), 10e3);
}
```

Comment: `taskState.return` is not a function on chrome 45.0.2454.93

Comment: @LiYinKong Yup, [Chorme doesn't support](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#generators_%GeneratorPrototype%.return) [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/return) yet. [Babel](http://babeljs.io/) however does, it you don't mind transpiling your code; which you will need to do anyway if you want your generator-based code to run in IE or Safari as they don't support generators at all at this point.